# SuiteScript Email Failure

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to send an email in a 2.0 suitescript (scheduled). My code is very simple:

```
email.send
({
    author: 123,
    recipients: 123,
    subject: 'Errors',
    body: 'Please see attachment'
})
```

That's it. The email shows up in the Sent Email list, which seems to show everything fine:

```
Sent Date 04/27/2021 17:21
Log Date 04/27/2021 17:21
From "<my name> (<my email address>)" <system@sent-via.netsuite.com>
Subject [SANDBOX] Errors
To Recipients <my name> (<my email address>)
CC Recipients  
BCC Recipients  
Message-ID <fknhf2pr4jqaxt5dmqc56ab2353384v9zj0qr1i6ke5fz9n3o7u6w0o8alojgm0w@netsuite.com>
Status Not Sent
Unchecked Compliance Verified
Body Please see attachment
```

I note, however, that in the sent email the RECIPIENT list is empty - my email does not appear; no emails do.

The email doesn't arrive. So no apparent errors - it just doesn't arrive, and NetSuite says it was not sent, although it doesn't seem to say why.

Answer (score 1):

Check Sandbox "email delivery preferences".  As an Administrator go to Setup > Company > Email > Email Preferences > Sandbox and Release Preview subtab (Sandbox Options heading).  There are options there to dictate who Sandbox emails are sent to.  You can reference Suite Answer Id 20152 for more information.  If there's still as issue confirm the specified employee internal id actually has an email address stored in the record.